# Get the indices from a list of numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a list of numpy arrays like below from where I want to fetch the indices values.

```
import numpy as np


new_list = list(np.array(['Black', 'Blue', 'Green']), np.array(['Horse', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Owl']))
```

I want indices of `new_list` to be an individual list like below. So, how can I fetch the indices of the arrays in a list ?

```
Expected Output:

[[0], [1], [2], [0], [1], [2], [3]]
```

Answer (score -1):

This snippet prints out the expected output:

```
import numpy as np


new_list = [
    np.array(["Black", "Blue", "Green"]),
    np.array(["Horse", "Dog", "Cat", "Owl"]), ]


indices = [[index] for string_list in new_list for index in range(len(string_list))]

print(indices)
```

Answer (score -1):

Iterates over each array contained in the new_list using a for loop, then iterates over each element of each array using another for loop by using range and len. Then append each element to a new list.